# CSS/Bootstrap Sticky scrolling effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I've created sticky scrolling effect (boxes are scrolling down and overlaping) using Elementor and Wordpress (here: http://195.78.66.87/~marwis93/brudnopis/).

Now I'am trying to move this effect to Bootstrap or pure CSS, any hint or idea how to this? I am not an expert not nothing works, sticky parameter does not work at all.

Comment: Looks like youll need JS for this, Have you made any progress with Bootstrap/CSS

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami: As far as I know it is possible with pure CSS. I am having a trobule with setting proper parametrs.